# How to use different storageStates for each test case or test case file?

Tags: typescript, playwright

How can I use different `storageState`s for test cases in the same file, and how can I change `storageState` between files?

At the moment, I use Storage state to delete `test.beforeEach(async ({ page })`.

Here's my code:

```js
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test'
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/marketplace/login.page'
import { loginData } from '../../test-data/login.data'

// TODO: Get developer env from .env file
test.describe('Marketplace login feature', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage

  // test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  //   const mainPage = new MainPage(page)

  //   await mainPage.goto()
  //   await mainPage.allowCookies.click()
  //   await mainPage.loginLink.click()

  // })
  test('User login with valid credentials using PC', async ({page}) => {
    // TODO: Probably move this somewhere
    const expectedString = 'xxx'
    loginPage = new LoginPage(page)
  
    await loginPage.login({
      userEmail: loginData.userEmail,
      userPassword: loginData.userPassword,
    })

    await expect(loginPage.myAccount).toHaveText(expectedString)
  })
```

I export a Storage JSON file and use it in playwright.config.ts:

```js
  trace: 'retain-on-failure',
  video: 'retain-on-failure',
  storageState: './Cookies.json'
},
```

But I wonder how can I use different `storageState`s on different test cases.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Configuration Scope](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-use-options#configuration-scopes)

You can define configuration scope in Playwright globally, per project, or per test as per your requirement.

In this case ,you may define the scope of configuration on test level by using `test.use` like below:

```
 test.use({storageState: 'UserA_storageState.json'});
        
 test("test for User A", async ({ page }) => {
           //code
 })
    
 test.use({storageState: 'UserB_storageState.json'});
        
 test("test for User B", async ({ page }) => {
           //code
 }
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-use-options#configuration-scopes